# mouse coordinates in MouseHover event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I know how to retrieve the mouse coordinate in a `PictureBox.Click` event though `e`

In a `PictureBox.MouseHover`, `e` does not return such information.

How do I get the mouse coordinates in a `MouseHover` event ? Is there a way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with visual studio.  Please re-tag your question with the language you are interested in.

Comment: `MouseMove` will give you those coordinates.

Comment: Please remember to tag your question appropriately. Visual Studio is just an IDE - it tells us nothing about the language or framework you're using. I'm assuming it is C# and Windows Forms - I've retagged it accordingly. Please change it if that was not correct.

Comment: I wanted to tag Visual Basic but the tag did not exist. It is different than Basic, right ?. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user3029534 Replace `c#` tag with `vb.net`. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to up-vote any answers that help, and accept the best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Control.MouseHover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "occurs when the mouse pointer rests on the control."

> A typical use of MouseHover is to display a tool tip when the mouse pauses on a control within a specified area around the control (the "hover rectangle"). The pause required for this event to be raised is specified in milliseconds by the MouseHoverTime property.

So this event is not raised only whenever the mouse is over the control - there is a delay associated. So the position is somewhat irrelevant, as the mouse could have moved somewhat during that delay.

Do you really need to be using this event?  As [Dan-o mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184304/mouse-coordinates-in-mousehover-event/20184445#comment30092006_20184304), [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) passes a [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) which does provide the coordinates, as you request. It may be the right option, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

To get the mouse position at *any time* though, you can use the [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) property. This will give you the *screen coordinates* of the cursor.  From here, you can call the [`Control.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method, to get the coordinates relative to a particular `Control`.