# How to get index of row when MouseHover in Radgridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, radgridview

i want to get index of any row that my mouse is above and not necessarily from the selected row.

```
 Private Sub RadGridView1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.MouseHover
            Try
                toolidx = RadGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                strphone = dsOrders.Tables(0).Rows(toolidx)("DeliveryPhone")

            Catch ex As Exception
                RadMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, projectName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error)
                errlog.WriteLog(ex.Message.ToString, Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString())
            End Try
        End Sub
```

the code above does what i want but for the selected row i want to  get the index of row when my mouse is over this row. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Old link on telerik](http://www.telerik.com/forums/finding-the-grid-row-item-under-the-mouse-pointer), very may well have changed, but there is example code in there available for download

Comment: the answer must be simpler :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the cell with the following instruction. Shouldn't be difficult to get the row and column index from it.

```
Dim cell As GridCellElement = TryCast(RadGridView1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(e.Location), GridCellElement)
```

As GetElementAtPoint could return element of GridView which are not necessarily Cells, DataCells to be more precise. Don't forget to check what is really under the cursor.

As the MouseHover event do not give information about coordinates, maybe you should use the MouseMove event instead or you could use the Cursor.Position Property.

Credit from
http://www.telerik.com/forums/determining-the-mouse-down-position-in-cell
and
[mouse coordinates in MouseHover event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184304/mouse-coordinates-in-mousehover-event)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer but e.location unfortunately is not accepted in mouseHover event  i dont want to click the cell i want just to hover it

Comment: Updated my answer about your location issue.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers maybe i need them  another time! i have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My real problem was... I wanted to add a tooltip in specific column and tooltip show the value of another column here is the code to do this.

```
Private Sub RadGridView1_ToolTipTextNeeded(sender As Object, e As ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.ToolTipTextNeeded
        Try
            Dim cell As GridDataCellElement = TryCast(sender, GridDataCellElement)

            If cell IsNot Nothing AndAlso cell.ColumnInfo.Name = "DeliveryName" Then    
                e.ToolTipText = cell.RowInfo.Cells.Item("DeliveryPhone").Value  

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            RadMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, projectName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error)
            errlog.WriteLog(ex.Message.ToString, Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```